# Optimal algorithm with graph

Tags: c++, memory, optimization, graph, task

The task:

The input is words :

[image]

Let:

[image]

Each word can be presented as the **n-2** words of length **3**:

[image]
[image]

Next:
Let, we have a graph **G**.

1)If the graph **G** have no vertex, for example Wi, so then put it;

2)For each pair of vertices [image]
add oriented edge or increase the weight of existing vertex by 1;

In the first line of input we take [image]
- amount of words;

**Output:**
In the first line print **V** - amount of vertices;

In the second line print **E** - amount of edges;

In the next line print the words corresponding to the ends of the vertex **e1** and weight of the oriented edge;

In the next line the same for **e2**

...

Until to the edge with number **E**

***Example with input and output:***
[image]

**I wrote a solution**, but it wasn't accepted due to "*Memory limit*" or "*Time limit*"(**depending on how I allocated memory in the adjacency matrix**).**I wonder about a better solution**, but nothing else comes to mind. In my humble opinion it's not bad solution)

So let's overview the solution:

**1)My adjacency matrix and base types:**

```
constexpr short increaseSize = 10;
using IndexType = uint16_t;
using MatrixElementType = uint16_t;
using VertexType = string;
```

---

```
class Matrix{
    using Vector = std::vector<MatrixElementType>;
    using Data = std::vector<Vector>;
    Data data{};
public:
    auto& operator() (const IndexType i,const IndexType j){
        return data[i][j];
    }
    auto increaseDimension(){
        auto size = data.size();
        bool newSize = false;
        if(size == data.capacity()) newSize = true;
        for(IndexType i = 0;i<size;++i)
        {
            if(newSize)data[i].reserve(size + increaseSize);
            data[i].push_back(0);
        }
        if(newSize)data.reserve(size + increaseSize);
        data.push_back(Vector(size+1,0));
    }
};
```

**2)Vertices:**

```
class Vertices{
public:
    using DataToIndex = std::unordered_map<VertexType,IndexType>;
private:
    DataToIndex dataToIndex{};
public:

    void add(const VertexType& vertex, const IndexType index){
        dataToIndex[vertex] = index;
    }

    const VertexType& getData(const IndexType index){
        for(const auto& element:dataToIndex)
            if(element.second == index) return element.first;
        return dataToIndex.begin()->first;
    }

    auto operator[](const VertexType& data) {
       struct Proxy{
          const IndexType index;
          bool exists;
          operator bool(){return exists;}
       };
    auto iterator = dataToIndex.find(data);
    return Proxy{iterator->second,iterator != dataToIndex.end()};
}

   auto exists(const VertexType& data){
      if(dataToIndex.find(data) == dataToIndex.end())
        return false;
     else return true;
   }
};
```

**3)And finally, Graph**

```
class Graph{
using Index = IndexType;
public:
    static constexpr char wordSize = 3;
private:
    Matrix matrix{};
    Vertices vertices{};
    IndexType amoutOfVertices = 0;
    IndexType amountOfEdges = 0;
public:
    inline void addVertex(const VertexType& str){
        if(vertices.exists(str)) return;
        vertices.add(str,amoutOfVertices);
        matrix.increaseDimension();
        ++amoutOfVertices;
    }
    inline void addEdge(const IndexType i,const IndexType j){
        if(matrix(i,j)== 0 ) ++amountOfEdges;
        ++matrix(i,j);
    }
    inline void addEdge(const VertexType& str1,const VertexType& str2){
        auto first = vertices[str1],
             second = vertices[str2];
        if(first && second)
            addEdge(first.index, second.index);
    }

   inline void out(){
        cout << amoutOfVertices << endl;
        cout << amountOfEdges << endl;
        IndexType i,j;
        MatrixElementType element;
        for(i = 0 ;i < amoutOfVertices;++i)
            for(j = 0;j< amoutOfVertices;++j)
                if((element = matrix(i,j))) {
                    cout << vertices.getData(i) << " ";
                    cout << vertices.getData(j) << " ";
                    cout << element << endl;
                }
      }

};
```

**4)Function to read(a bit ugly, but it saves our memory):**

```
void readText(){
    Graph graph;
    IndexType T;
    cin >> T;
    getchar();
    for(IndexType mainIndex = 0;mainIndex< T;++mainIndex){
        wordPreparing(graph);
    }
    graph.out();
}


void wordPreparing(Graph& graph ){
    string previousiWord{},iword{};
    char newChar = ' ';
    for(char i = 0;i< Graph::wordSize;++i){
        iword += getchar();
    }
    graph.addVertex(iword);

    newChar = getchar();
    while(newChar != '\n'){
        previousiWord = iword;
        for(char i = 0;i< Graph::wordSize-1;++i)
            iword[i] = iword[i+1];
        iword[Graph::wordSize - 1] = newChar;
        newChar = getchar();
        graph.addVertex(iword);
        graph.addEdge(previousiWord, iword);
    }
}
```

**And we get it:**

[image]

**or it:**
[image]

**The task requires: 6.0 s and 128 Mb.**

**Even if there is another solution, I would be immensely grateful if someone would comment on my approach)**

Comment: just a remark: `return data[i-1][j-1];`  this opens the door to subtle bugs and lots of confusion, you better stick to the C++ convention of `0` based indexing, mixing `0` based and `1` based indexing in the same code isnt nice

Comment: You have one `Matrix` and reserve space in both dimensions regularly.
If you reserve a fixed amount at start you won't be spending time checking if it's time to increase it - and you can also make it just big enough to fit within the memory limit.

Comment: @user463035818, thank you for remark, I know it and thought about how to fix, but the fact is std::map object returns from subscript [ data ] 0 if there is no vertex and a positive number else, and it more convenient to use **return data[i-1][j-1]** in this case unfortunately;

Comment: you are using one problem as excuse for a different one ;). Dont trade convenience for correctness and performance. Unless you explcitly want the map to insert a value for the key in case it does not exist you should be using `map::find` not `map::operator[]`

Comment: I don't understand what you said about `std::map` object and I also can't find `std::map` anywhere in your code. Edit: There's a `std::unordered_map` in there I see now ... but still don't get why you can't use zero based indexing. Also: `operator DataToIndex()` looks expensive. Do you want to return a copy of the `unordered_map`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo,  user463035818 answered it and I understand that it's a better to use  map::find; 
For example, if we write:
**std::map<string,int> object;**
**object["abc"]  == 0;**
I'm about it
:)
**UPD**:I do not use it, I forgot to clean; I just tried everything to make it work)

Comment: actually I was more refering to const-correctness. You cannot call `operator[]` on a `const` map

Comment: @nnuttertools Did you try to create a fixed sized `Matrix` and skip the call to `increaseDimension()`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Yes, but absolutely without **increaseDimension ()** does not work; I assume that the matrix size is about 7 * 1000, but it is difficult to guess the number bytes to bytes, my solution also passes 17-18 tests, and 17 fails due to a Time limit, and if I increase **IncreaseSize**, it will fail due to memory limit on 18;

Comment: Log the final size of the `Matrix` when you run the program using the `increaseDimension()` function, then in your next version of the program. `reserve` space for exacly those dimensions and comment out the call to `increaseDimension()`. If you are using the same input data, it should work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I send it to a server and can't control the input unfortunately. I suppose, the server gives random input data to a "particular topic" for each test;